# Spring Cloud AWS SQS Listener not working

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to configure a Listner for AWS SQS whenever a file is uploaded in Amazon S3. I have configured the event from S3 so that a message is dumped in the SQS when a  file is uploaded in S3.

Now I am using Spring cloud(version - 1.2.1.RELEASE) to configure a SQS Listner for the S3 event.
Below are my config files :

**aws-config.xml**

```
<aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="*******" secret-key="******"/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:context-region  region="ap-south-1" />  
<aws-context:context-resource-loader/>  
<aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener max-number-of-messages="10" 
wait-time-out="20" visibility-timeout="3600""/>
```

AwsResourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
 @EnableSqs
 @ImportResource("classpath:/aws-config.xml")
 @EnableRdsInstance(databaseName = "******", 
               dbInstanceIdentifier = "*****", 
               password = "******")
 public class AwsResourceConfig {
@SqsListener(value = "souviksqs", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void receiveNewFileUpload(S3EventNotification event) {
    try {
        if ( event != null && !CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty( event.getRecords() ) && event.getRecords().get( 0 ) != null ) {
            S3Entity entry = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3();
            System.out.println("############ File Uploaded to ###################### " + entry.getBucket().getName() + "/" + entry.getObject().getKey());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading the SQS message " + e);

    }
}
```

}

Whenever there is a file uploaded in S3,a message is added in SQS.
But the SQSListener is not working.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` and not `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging`.

Also if that isn't the case, make sure `SimpleMessageListenerContainer's` auto startup is not set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue and found out that it was a versioning problem.
Spring Boot 3.0x requires Spring Cloud AWS 3.0x and AWS Java SDK 2.x

[Click here](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws#compatibility-with-spring-project-versions) to get detailed info on Spring Cloud and AWS Compatability versions

In order to create a Consumer in **Spring Boot 3.0**, you need to use @EnableScheduling Bean in your main application. Then you need to use @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000) above the receive method. @Scheduled bean replaces the @SqsListener here. You can visit this [link](https://javatodev.com/how-to-use-amazon-sqs-with-spring-boot/) for more info.

Comment: Why not use Spring Cloud AWS 3.0? We’re already in RC and GA should be out in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Using EnableScheduling is different pattern. It will invoke every fixedDelay seconds.